# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string - Msg 241, Level 16, State 1,

Tags: sql-server

I keep getting the following error to my code when I either try to set it as `cast()` or `convert()`.  Nothing seems to work.

Query:

```
SELECT TOP 100
    *
FROM [OptionsDW].[dbo].[Octagon5]
WHERE CONVERT(datetime2, CurrDate, 121) 
          BETWEEN CAST('2010-01-01' AS date) AND CAST('2010-06-31' AS date)
```

Result:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 Conversion failed when converting
>   date and/or time from character string.

I know there are many similar queries but none of them helped with my problem.

Comment: Did you look at data for `CurrDate`?

Answer (score 0):

There are only 30 days in June so `CAST('2010-06-31' AS date)` in your where statement will fail